# Increasing and decreasing size of search box with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a search box which when you click it, it increases in width, if you click outside of it, it checks to see if there is a value, and if not, decrease back to the original size.

I thought the following code would do the trick, but it does a little more than expected - ie you can keep clicking the box and it will just keep growing :D

ie

```
$('#search').live('click',function(){

    $(this).animate({width:'+=60px'},300);

}).live('blur',function(){

    if($(this).val() == '') {

        $(this).animate({width:'-=60px'},300);

    }

});
​
```

I made a JS fiddle of the situation 
http://jsfiddle.net/7V93H/

How would one go about turning this into a toggle so that it performs properly?

Comment: Your function is working fine.

Comment: What happens if you keep clicking the input? Does it keep growing (its not supposed to)? Maybe its a Chrome thing - what browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, which one is bothering you ?

Comment: Tested in chrome, ff and IE, works fine.

Comment: It does not work fine, it keeps adding to the searchbox whenever you click it, that's the way that code works.

Comment: +1 for the `.on` advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
$('#search').live('focus',function(){

    $(this).animate({width:($(this).width()+60)+'px'},300);

}).live('blur',function(){

    if($(this).val() == '')
        $(this).animate({width:($(this).width()-60)+'px'},300);

});
```

Future proof it by changing `.live` to `.on`.

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/7V93H/11/
        ​

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't the code you just wrote do the same thing? I am using live because this stuff is being loaded in an ajax request. I should probably use 'on()' though :|

Comment: Yeah, I did click it.. I can keep clicking it and it grows and grows and grows. Chrome and FF :(

Comment: Got it. I changed `.live('click'` to `.live('focus'`.

Comment: This is probably one of the "wrongest" answer, as it uses a deprecated function, but I guess it was the right one after all?

Answer (score 3):

```
var W = $('#search').width();

$(document).on({
    click: function(){
        if ($(this).width()==W) {
            $(this).animate({width: '+=60px'},300);
        }
    },
    blur: function(){
        if($(this).val() == '' && $(this).width()>W) {
            $(this).animate({width:'-=60px'},300);
        }
    }
}, '#search');​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nZGrB/)

A better idea would be to just replace click with focus, and an even better idea would be to set a width on the searchbox, and animate an actual value instead of adding width to an existing value.

Something like:

```
$(document).on('focus blur', '#search', function(){
    $(this).animate({width: $(this).width()==200 ? 100 : 200},300);
});
```

[Another FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nZGrB/1/)

Comment: Why someone is down voting on our answers while these are working ?

Comment: Well, your answer actually does'nt work, as it's not delegated, and your use of .on() is equalent to click() not live(), mine on the other hand should work just fine :-) , I did see you updated your answer for dynamic elements, so there really is no reason it should be downvoted, but who cares anyhow?

Comment: Yes! was just adding that above :-)

Comment: Interesting approach there. I will study it and learn from it - thanks!

Comment: Your second better idea works exactly perfect. The ones above are wrong as once text is inputted, they will continue to grow with each click.

Your's should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
var extended = false;

$('#search').live('click',function(){
    if (!extended)
    {
       $(this).animate({width:'+=60px'},300);
       extended = true;
    }
}).live('blur',function(){

    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).animate({width:'-=60px'},300);
        extended = false;
    }
});
​
```

Comment: Whoever down voted this, care to explain why? The provided answer works as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Samples above have some issues. For example: if you type something in search box and blur it out, the box continues grows indefinitely. To fix it, you must put an empty conditional or placeholder conditional there. This following example is working on:

```
$(function() {

    $('#nav-search-input').focus(function() {
        //user has clicked on the input
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).animate({width:'+=120px'},200);
        }
    });

    $('#nav-search-input').blur(function() {
        //user has clicked off the input

        //check its value
        if(!$(this).val()) {
            //return to old size
            $(this).animate({width:'-=120px'},200);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Live is deprecated, try this

```
$('#search').on('focus',function(){
    var $w=$(this).width();
    $(this).animate({width:$w+60+'px'},300);
})
.on('blur',function(){
    var $w=$(this).width();
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).animate({width:$w-60+'px'},300);
    }
});
```

An example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7V93H/13/). Working in chrome, ff and IE.

**Update: [This one](http://jsfiddle.net/7V93H/14/) for dynamically added element.**

Comment: Why define `$w` to only get used once.

Comment: To make it clean inside the animate's argument and because my answer is correct/working so why down vote ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `live()` because as of jQuery 1.7 it's deprecated.  Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

I don't think it's a good idea to use click as the binder, why don't you use blur and focus?

```
$('#search').focus(function() {
   // User has clicked on the input
   $(this).animate({width:'+=60px'},300);
});

$('#search').blur(function() {
   // User has clicked off the input

   // Check its value
   if(!$(this).val()) {
      // Return to old size
      $(this).animate({width:'-=60px'},300);
   }
});
```

If you want the change to be more slick, you can look into using [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to control the speed and motion of the change.